# No render elements from array - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript3.0

Project based on Typescript vs ReactJS.

**This is render code :**

```
return (
            <div ref={this.myRef} style={this.state.myStyle} >
              {this.state.sections.map((sectionsItem: AppI.SectionI) => {
                if (this.state.activeSection === sectionsItem.name) {
                  console.log("TEST :", sectionsItem.elements );
                  sectionsItem.elements.map((element: React.ReactElement<any>, index: number) => {
                    return <span key={index} >{element}</span>;
                  });
                }
              })}
            </div>
           );
```

In debugger I can see that 'elements' are not empty but it doesn't render in html.

Any suggestion ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an extra `return` statement:
Change: `sectionsItem.elements.map` to `return sectionsItem.elements.map`:
Your inner `.map` returns elements but the outer `.map` has no return statement:

```
return (
        <div ref={this.myRef} style={this.state.myStyle} >
          {this.state.sections.map((sectionsItem: AppI.SectionI) => {
            if (this.state.activeSection === sectionsItem.name) {
              console.log("TEST :", sectionsItem.elements );
              return sectionsItem.elements.map((element: React.ReactElement<any>, index: number) => {
                return <span key={index} >{element}</span>;
              });
            }
          })}
        </div>
       );
```